# Creating a quiz with Django

Tags: django

I'm trying to build a quiz using Django but I've got some doubts. I've got my piece of code in which the text of the questions and the answers are displayed. I'm also able to read which answers did the user select for that question.
The problem now is that I want this to be repeated like 10 times, I mean, I want the user to answer **10 different questions**. I was wondering which is the best method to do so, I've thought about saving in the database the user which is doing the quiz and the questions he/she has already answered but I don't like much that method. I've been thinking about using session cookies but I'm not familiar to them.

Comment: You should include your code, view, models, forms and template in your question. Your question is pretty open-ended and has votes to close for being too vague. Adding additional information will make it less vague and increase the possibility of someone being able to answer it.

Comment: This might e useful to you https://medium.com/@nsjcorps/create-a-quiz-application-with-django-rest-framework-react-redux-part-one-f0fcae5103fd